# learning display, position, and floats. tried a simple practice of floats and it's not working out

Tags: html, css

I created a quick simple html doc to practice floats thinking, with such an easy example that it would work straight away. but something weird happened.

I just wanted to float 2 divs next to each other with equal width and size. I used the exact same tagging and words to make it completely easy to see how it was working. However, somehow #content had padding above the title whereas #content1 had none and it made the "boxes" way out of sync. However, when I added a padding of only 0.1px to #content1 they both fall in line together and have the exact same amount of padding? I just don't seem to be grasping even the most basic concepts...Here is the code I used anyway -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Float</title>

    <style>
        p {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #content {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: grey;
        }

        #content1 {
            padding-top: 0.1px;
            margin-left: 50%;
            width: 50%;
            background-color: grey;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>Ra ra banjo banjo</h1>
        <p>Welcome to the Ra ra banjo banjo page. Ra ra banjo banjo. Ra          ra banjo banjo. Ra ra banjo banjo.</p>
        <p>(Ra ra banjo banjo)</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content1">
        <h1>Ra ra banjo banjo</h1>
        <p>Welcome to the Ra ra banjo banjo page. Ra ra banjo banjo. Ra   ra banjo banjo. Ra ra banjo banjo.</p>
        <p>(Ra ra banjo banjo)</p>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that HTML Elements have some default styles like padding or margin, which affect your element's total width. You can easily change those with the css using `*`, which will affect all the elements in your document.

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    /* 
        etc., you can add here whatever you need to be a global style
        and rewrite some things afterwards in the specific classes, ids, ...
    */
}
```

If you're floating the blocks, you need to think about the total of the elements, so not only about the `width` property, but also about thier `padding`, `margin` and `border`. If the summarised (total) width of elements you're floating is bigger than their parent's width they will not be floated.

So, in your exercise it would look like this:

```
*, p {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#content {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: grey;
}

#content1 {
    /*
      padding-top: 0.1px; - this is unnecessary 
      margin-left: 50%; 
      this margin makes the element 100% wide 
      (50% width + 50% margin-left), so it will not be floated to the 
      #content in your code as they would have the 150% of total width
      and it's 50% more than the parent's width 
      (of course, parent's width is always 100%)
    */
    width: 50%;
    background-color: grey;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hey, the suggestion of changing the default styles fixed the problem and removed the need for the padding-top:0.1px! However, when I remove margin-left: 50% and just keep width #content1 drops below #content. I tried inline-block etc, but without margin-left, it still falls below? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: you have no float on the second element in your example. It will probably be the problem. Also, there is no need for that `padding-top` you're using.. here is the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r4xuLes6/

Comment: oh wow, I was adding float: right; to #content1 when I first tried! So because the second div is below floating it left floats it left to the nearest div? I managed to get mine working via this (after changing the default styles you suggested) before I received your last reply -

    #content {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      background-color: grey;
    }

    #content1 {
      margin-left: 50%;
      background-color: grey;
   }

Comment: If you want the elements to be floated you need to have a float property on each item. In your case the float is missing on the #content1, so it's not floated. Margin just adds the offset to your element and it looks like it is floated, but it's not (try to resize your browser's window and you'll see). 
I recommend you to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFGBNv2KeVU and read the documentation, you can also check the W3Cschools for better understanding.

And of course if my answer was helpful for you I'll be glad if you can click the up vote or mark it as correct. Good day

Comment: And of course if my answer was helpful or correct, I'll be glad if you mark it as correct or up-vote. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I fully understand your problem. Why it’s not working? Your problem is clearly understanding the **CSS** `box-model`. Floting **CSS** depend on parent element box modeling. Your main problem is `box-model` not `display`, `position` and `float`.

**How box-model work?**

CSS `box-model` is rectangular boxes. `box-model` are describes the content of the space an element. Every box has ***four edges***: The **margin edge**, **border edge**, **padding edge** and **content edge**. The content area is real content of the element. It has a **background**, a **color** or an **image**, **text** etc. And it’s located inside the content edge. its dimensions are the `content width`, or `content-box` `width`, and the `content height`, or `content-box` `height`.

CSS `box-model` used `box-sizing` property.

`box-sizing` global value:

```
box-sizing: inherit;
box-sizing: initial;
box-sizing: unset;
```

`box-sizing` keyword value:

```
box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: padding-box; /* Only Firefox implemented this value, and it was removed in Firefox 50. */
```

> content-box:

If a box `width: 450px`. Then you apply `border: 5px solid red;`. Result box `width: 460px;`.

```css
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.content-box{
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 450px;
}
.with-border{
  border: 5px solid #121212;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-box">Without border</div>
<div class="content-box with-border">With border</div>
```

> border-box:

If a box `width: 450px`. Then you apply `border: 5px solid red;`. Result box `width: 450px;`.

```css
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.border-box{
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 450px;
}
.with-border{
  border: 5px solid #121212;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-box">Without border</div>
<div class="border-box with-border">Width border</div>
```

> Syntax & Uses:

```
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

or

```
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

You can use it with any `class` or any `ID`.

If you clear understand the the box-model then you will understand the display, position and floating.